# How can I import my OpenApi 3.0 to Api Platform? (contract first)

Tags: symfony4, openapi, api-platform.com, openapi-generator

I would like to use Api Platform (symfony 4) to make an API Rest. Before starting to work with API Platform, I create the Openapi 3.0 (swagger) with Api Generator. So I define the contract first.

So now, I want to import from Openapi to API Platform my schema but I don't know if we can do that.

I know it is possible to export from API Plateform to Openapi (to create Documentation), I think it is impossible to import.

Anyone have an idea?
Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

A little late but if it helps. API patform propose a tool. I just tried it, unfortunately all the configuration is not applied. It only creates the entities. It's a good start but it's not completely compatible with OpenAPI.
If anyone is interested, you will find more information:
https://api-platform.com/docs/schema-generator/getting-started/#openapi-generation
https://api-platform.com/docs/schema-generator/configuration/